# Using generics to make a swap method

Tags: java, generics

I'm having trouble with a basic concept in my book. I am supposed to make a method swap(); that swaps positions with first and second using generics. I believe my method is correct however I changed the code in the pair class from T,S to T because I was getting errors and thought that would solve the issue but this is not the case. My problem is that I now get a lot of compile time errors in my demo class and I cannot find a solution.

```
public class Pair<T>
    {
       private T first;
       private T second;



   public Pair(T firstElement, T secondElement)
   {
      first = firstElement;
      second = secondElement;
   }


   public T getFirst() { return first; }

   public T getSecond() { return second; }

  public void swap()
  {

   T temp = first;
    first = second;
    second = temp;
  }

   public String toString() { return "(" + first + ", " + second + ")"; }
}
```

This is the compile time error that I am getting.

```
PairDemo.java:23: error: wrong number of type arguments; required 1
   public static Pair<String, Integer> firstContaining(
                     ^
PairDemo.java:6: error: wrong number of type arguments; required 1
      Pair<String, Integer> result = firstContaining(names, "a");
          ^
PairDemo.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
      swap();
      ^
  symbol:   method swap()
  location: class PairDemo
PairDemo.java:30: error: wrong number of type arguments; required 1
            return new Pair<String, Integer>(strings[i], i);
                           ^
PairDemo.java:33: error: wrong number of type arguments; required 1
      return new Pair<String, Integer>(null, -1);
```

This is my demo class

```
public class PairDemo
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      String[] names = { "Tom", "Diana", "Harry" };
      Pair<String, Integer> result = firstContaining(names, "a");
      System.out.println(result.getFirst());
      System.out.println("Expected: Diana");
      System.out.println(result.getSecond());
      System.out.println("Expected: 1");
      swap();
   }


   public static Pair<String, Integer> firstContaining(
      String[] strings, String sub)
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++)
      {
         if (strings[i].contains(sub))
         {
            return new Pair<String, Integer>(strings[i], i);
         }
      }
      return new Pair<String, Integer>(null, -1);
   }
}
```

Comment: Your `Pair<T>` requires one type `T`, you provide two: `String` and `Integer`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the elements of your Pair to have distinct types you have to make your Pair class having two generic parameters: Pair<T,U> and make second a field of type U. Swap then obviously returns a Pair<U,T> and cannot permute the *this* reference.

It will be like

```
public Pair<U,T> swap() {
  return new Pair(second, first);
}
```

Comment: How would I go about calling that method?

Comment: Pair<String, Integer> pair1 = new Pair("Foo",3);
Pair<Integer, String> swappedPair = pair1.swap();

Now it holds: swappedPair.first == 3 and swappedPair.second == "foo"

Comment: I can't seem to comprehend this because my book wants me to modify the pair class to have the same type and then add a swap method.

Comment: I found something interesting. I called result.swap(); from the last method given to me and it swapped from Diana, 1 to 1, Diana so that seems to have done the trick.

Comment: If you want to follow the book you talk about Pair<T> and then you cannot write a Pair of a String and a number, because these are different types and you wrote the class in a way that only one is acceptable. Your swap method is in that case correct. Note however that the swap method modifies the state of your object ("mutability") and that is something expert programmers usually dislike. When you are through your book read "Effective Java" it will surely make people hire you for your Java skills ;)