# how to swap different type of generic in java?

Tags: java

I have a task to create the "Pair" class, which will store 2 values ​​of any type <K, T>. The class contains a swap method, which should swap the first and second element.

My class look like this and the swap method doesn't work. What implementation of the method will be the correct?

```
class Pair<K, T> {
    private K firstValue;
    private T lastValue;

    Pair(K firstValue, T lastValue) {
        this.firstValue = firstValue;
        this.lastValue = lastValue;
    }

    public K first() {
        return firstValue;
    }

    public T last() {
        return lastValue;
    }

    public void replaceFirst(K newFirstValue) {
        firstValue = newFirstValue;
    }

    public void replaceLast(T newLastValue) {
        lastValue = newLastValue;
    }

    public void swap() {
        K temp = firstValue;
        firstValue = (K) lastValue;
        lastValue = (T) temp;
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: What do you expect to happen when `K` and `T` are incompatible types?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include an example and how the result of the `swap()` method should look like. Include multiple examples if possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using generics to make a swap method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28991757/using-generics-to-make-a-swap-method)

Comment: Maybe instead of creating method which would attempt swap values in current Pair, create method which will return *separate pair* with swapped values? Something like `public Pair<T,K> swapped(){return new Pair<>(this.lastValue, this.firstValue);}`. This way from `Pair<K,T>` you will create *separate* `Pair<T,K>` which can have its generic types set in reversed order.

Answer (score 4):

That doesn't work, because as defined, the task at hand **is impossible with that signature**.

Consider a `Pair<String, Integer>`. If you swap that, then all of a sudden it'd be a `Pair<Integer, String>`, and things cannot magically change their type midflight, that's just not how java works. Hence, this question **cannot possibly be done** in the way you've set it up.

Alternatives that do work:

### Homogenous pair

Instead you can forcibly state that any pair has the property that the type of the 'left' and the 'right' side must be identical. That doesn't mean they both have to be, say, String - one can be String and one can be Integer, but if you do that, the pair is to be considered a `Pair<Object>` - i.e. a pair has just one type parameter and that reflects the thing both left and right are. In that case, swap is no problem at all, and you need to add zero casts to do it. just:

```
class Pair<E> {
  E left, right;

  public Pair(E left, E right) {
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
  }

  ...

  public void swap() {
    E tmp = left;
    left = right;
    right = tmp;
  }
}
```

and voila.

Of course, it's really bizarre to add a constraint that a pair must have homogenous types like this.

### Don't swap in place, return a new pair

When you, say, cast an integer to a double, you don't *change the variable*. Instead, the expression returns a new  value. As an example:

```
double x = 5.5;
(int) x;
```

This doesn't compile. Even if it did (say, we go with `System.out.println((int) x);`, that doesn't mean the value of x is now 5. It is still 5.5 `(int) x` **does not modify `x` in any way** - it returns a new value. You can make your pair work the same way - `swap()` **does not** modify the pair at all, but it does return an entirely new pair:

```
public class Pair<K, T> {
  private K left;
  private T right;

  public Pair<T, K> swapped() {
    return new Pair<T, K>(right, left);
  }
}
```

SLIGHT EDIT: I renamed the method to `swapped`. Naming is tricky, and `swap` implies that the state of the pair object changes, which it does not. `swapped` far more accurately conveys the idea that it just makes a new pair.

Simple, no need for casts. Callers would have to do something with the returned value, though. This:

```
Pair<String, String> hi = new Pair<>("Hello", "World");
hi.swapped();
```

does nothing at all (because `swapped()` makes a new pair and returns it - ignoring what it returns, as above, means nothing happens). They'd have to write:

```
Pair<String, String> hi = new Pair<>("Hello", "World");
hi = hi.swapped();
```

And that would work fine. In addition, this would fail, and that's a good thing:

```
Pair<Integer, String> hi = new Pair<>(5, "Hi");
hi = hi.swapped(); // nope, fails to compile
```

That's good because *it should fail*: That code makes no sense. If you swap em around, you'd have a `Pair<String, Integer>`, and, you can't magically change the type of a local variable just by invoking a method. You can only make a new variable. This'd be fine:

```
Pair<Integer, String> hi = new Pair<>(5, "Hi");
Pair<String, Integer> hello = hi.swapped(); // no prob!
```

### An important note

Pair is bad. It's not 'java like'. People who write Pair classes fail to understand that java is at its core a highly nominal language: Things have names and that's good. Hence, Pair is almost never a good idea. For example, imagine this code:

```
public class University {
  /**
   * @return The student; pair.left is their name, pair.right is their student id. */
  public Pair<String, Long> lookupStudentByBirthDate(LocalDate date) {
     ...
  }
}
```

That's crappy code. Java is nominal: if you have a concept of 'a student', then **make a type called `Student` to represent it**. This is the correct way to do it:

```
public class University {
  public static record Student(String name, long id) {}

  public Student lookupByBirthDate(LocalDate birthDate) {
    ...
  }
}
```

The API is much nicer now, for many reasons:

- With `Pair<String, Long>` it's so difficult to know what the heck that represents, the method is pretty much forced to have an unwieldy, long name - it needs to be called `lookupStudent` so that a casual reader of this API knows what it is without having to read through all of that code (in the sense that they are no longer directly familiar with it, and **all** programmers are on any but the most academically tiny of projects: You can't remember every nook and cranny of a larger project either even if you wrote *all* of it yourself). Now, as it returns `Student`, it's clear from context and we no longer need to do that.
- I have a pair now. I need to look stuff up to know.. was the name 'left' and the id 'right' or was it the other way around?
- If you want student-specific utility you have a place for it - the `Student` class. You can't add a method to your `Pair` class that makes no sense except for students. You, of course, can and should do that if we have a dedicated `Student` class.

Comment: Yes, yes, yes.  Thank you for pointing out that a Pair (or Tuple) class is a poor design from the start.